# DisplayLink (ASUS MB16AH) USB-C device not recognised

Tags: usb, displaylink

A brand-new ASUS ZenScreen MB16AH bought as a replacement for an older USB screen does not want to connect via USB-C.

All the s/w is at its latest for the time of writing:

- **OS**: Ubuntu 22.04
- **Kernel**: 5.15.0-40-generic
- **EVDI kernel**: 1.11.0 of
- **DisplayLink**: 5.6.0-59.176

The screen works via HDMI, but shows *no signal* if connected via USB-C. The spec for my laptop says that all USB ports are USB 3.1. An older version of ASUS MB169B+ works just fine.

Running `journalctl -b` after connecting the monitor returns this log:

```
Jun 24 11:17:59 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 70 using xhci_hcd
Jun 24 11:17:59 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 24 11:18:00 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 24 11:18:00 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 71 using xhci_hcd
Jun 24 11:18:00 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 24 11:18:00 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 24 11:18:00 mx-zen kernel: usb usb1-port2: attempt power cycle
Jun 24 11:18:01 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 72 using xhci_hcd
Jun 24 11:18:01 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 24 11:18:01 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 24 11:18:01 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: device not accepting address 72, error -71
Jun 24 11:18:01 mx-zen kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 73 using xhci_hcd
```

and on it goes trying forever.

The monitor is definitely powered on as it displays the *no signal* message and goes to sleep (amber light).